# How do I make a 110V fan turn on when the thermostat turns the AC on?

Tags: wiring, thermostat

I have installed a new a/c with thermostat...easy enough, but thought to add a fan to the mix. Basically, I'd like to add a fan to increase ventilation into a second room that would turn on whenever the A/C turns on. I know you can run to multiple low voltage devices off a single thermostat, but what would be required to add a 110 fan so that it turns on exactly when the A/C turns on?

Thanks,
Pradhan

Comment: Is that air conditioner of the commodity in-the-window variety?  Or is it part of a central system?

Answer (score 7):

All you'd need is a relay.  You'll need one with a coil rated for 24VAC (or whatever the thermostat voltage is), and a contact rated to handle the current draw of the fan at line voltage.

- Connect the ungrounded (hot) feed to the `Common` terminal of the relay.
- Connect the ungrounded (hot) wire for the fan, to the `Normally Open (NO)` terminal of the relay.
- Connect the grounded (neutral) from the feed, to the grounded (neutral) of the fan.
- Connect all grounding conductors.
- Connect a wire from the `G` terminal on the thermostat, to one of the coil contacts on the relay.
- Connect a wire from the `C (common)` terminal of the A/C transformer.

When the thermostat calls for `COOL`, it should turn on the fan as well.

[image]
<sup>*Didn't add it to the diagram, but it's probably a good idea to have a fuse on the `R` wire.*</sup>

Comment: Any chance you could include a diagram of this? :)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I've seen the RIB2401B relay mentioned. Will that do the trick for the relay?

Comment: @DarthCaniac How's that?

Comment: @Tester101 Love it!

Comment: @Tester101 does this work for heating and AC, or just if the AC is running?

Comment: @DarthCaniac any time the thermostat energizes the `G` terminal. Which is usually if you turn the fan switch to ON, or during a call for COOL.  If you wanted it to work for heat too,  you'd need to work in the `W` terminal somehow as well.

Comment: @ Tester someone needs to get you a copy of InkScape :-)

Answer (score 0):

The relay will work great, your other option is to use one of these [https://www.amazon.com/BCTINT-10031-010-Automated-Vacuum-Switch/dp/B0035YGLZG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0035YGLZG)

They are used to turn on a vacuum when a tool starts running, most of them also have a delay built in so the vacuum would run for a few seconds after the tool shuts off.